# Python Usage of time.sleep

Tags: python, time

I have a label which I would like to move slowly to a fixed place at the end.
Using Label.move (x,y) , it goes instanly there. Therefore I tried to make a loop and using time.sleep to make it go there more slowly.
Unfortunately, the loop takes longer yes, but the label just moves in one go at the end. I don't understand why.

```
label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 0, 51, 71))

def move_label:
    variable = 0        
    while label.y() < 300:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        variable += 1
        label.move(360, variable)  # X is fixed to 360, lets use Y to move it vertically.
```

Comment: That's because the UI needs to be able to refresh at some point. Have a look if there's a `.refresh()`, `.update()` or `.invalidate()` method somewhere. Be aware that your way will make the UI unresponsive. You should have a look on how to use timers.

Comment: OK i understand. I didn't find refresh or anything like that. I use PyQt5

Comment: A good IDE like PyCharm should suggest methods. I'm not familiar with Qt, but there should be something like `label.repaint()`.

Comment: YES! label.repaint() ! that works ! BIG THX